# Why does this inside this work

Tags: javascript, oop

I know this works but why does it work?  Is the nest this.method attaching itself to the main object or is it attaching itself to the non nested this.method?

```
function device(){
    this.disconnect = function(){
        this.disconnected = function(){
             console.log("Disconnected from: " + self.name);
        }
    bluetooth.disconnect(this.disconnected,onBlueToothDisableError);
    }
}
```

Any reference to point me to best practices?

Comment: You'd have to show more of the relevant code and how it's called for us to understand what's going on.

Comment: Judging by the code that's available, I would assume that this code is within one object, and both are referencing vars within the object (disconnect/disconnected).  disconnected is being defined in disconnect, and then is called via callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `this` it doesn't matter at all where or how the function is defined. `this` is **only** defined by how a function is called, for each call individually.

The code you gave works because `self` refers to the global object and `name` is a property of the window global object in browsers which is a string representing the window name.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this was exactly what type of answer I was looking for.